# Custom code is not executing in SSRS 2008 when rendering as PDF

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dll, reporting-services

UPDATE: Ok so the custom code works in SSRS 2008 report services but not when I render the report as PDF.  The code is trying to create a dynamic report title in the master report header.

It runs great in report services but when I save as PDF only the value from the last subreport (the last time the custom code is executed on the report) is showing on all headers...

How can I get the PDF render to correctly execute the custom code for each subreport??

---

Previous question details here...

I was using a Code module in my SSRS 2008 report but it was not functioning correctly after I deployed the report.

I am now trying to create a custom code assembly to do the same thing however I'm receiving the error:

```
> [rsErrorLoadingCodeModule] Error while loading code module: 

>> SSRSDynamicRptTitle, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>> PublicKeyToken=null.
>> 
>> Details: Could not load file or assembly 'SSRSDynamicRptTitle,
>> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>> dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>> specified.   C:\DEV\KPI\APKPIReports\APKPIReports\MasterReport2.rdl
```

I have copied the dll to here:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`
here
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`
and here:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.SQL2008VANILLA\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin`

but still no dice.

Here is the code from the module I am trying to turn into an assembly:

```
Public Class DynamicRptTitle

    Public Shared myTitle As String

    Public Shared Function SetRptTitle(ByRef t As String) As Boolean

        myTitle = t
        Return False 'not hidden

    End Function

End Class
```

Originally I just had the shared variable `myTitle` and the shared function `SetRptTitle` in the Code portion of the project which worked perfectly in SSRS 2008R2, but not in 2008.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Meh, ok so I had copied the dll to the wrong folders.  Apparently I needed it here:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

and here:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`

I was copying it to the wrong version of VS...

I also changed the assembly name to the same name as the dll/namespace since the GAC said that was a good idea. Smart guy, that GAC.

Anyhow it's 'almost' working. It still works in my local dev environment but not when it's deployed. On the deployed report the last value I plug into the dll is repeated throughout the entire report. Are there any special considerations when deploying an assembly?  Maybe I need to revisit GAC...

Comment: Have you tried registering it in the GAC?

Comment: I've also had this error if my project had dependencies (other DLLs) that were not available (in the GAC, etc).  Have you removed any unnecessary dependencies from your project?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... My project is fairly simple with no other dependencies (to my knowledge). The only reference I have is to this new dll. Also, I'm not familiar with GAC but I'm looking at same articles on it right now.

Comment: Similar problem. Two tablixes, each fed from same dataset.  One reports on the first half the row (first 4+3 columns), the other data from the 2nd half (first 4 and last 4 columns).  Report and column headers for the tablixes are different.  Works fine in report viewer.  On export to Word, PDF, XLS, etc, it loses it's d@mned mind. I created a 2nd data set,  dropped unused columns from each, and FINALLY go the exports to mostly work.  Mostly.  I have a hidden field that does a DS lookup based on a key in the report dataset.  Hidden field is then used in header.  Only prints 1st instance.